# php the onclick function based input type date

Tags: php, date

User chooses the date , month and year and then press a button to show him the value of database based on the day he picked
I do not know where is the problem in the code

```
<style>
.button {border-radius: 8px;} 
.button1 {font-size: 20px;}
</style>
<form>

 إختر التاريخ : <input type="date" name="bday" id="dat"><br>

    <button type=button class="button button1" onclick="document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = myFunction(document.getElementById('dat').value)">إظهار الإستهلاك اليومي</button>
<hr>
<span id="data" ></span> 
</form>

<script>// <![CDATA[
    function myFunction($x) {
       $current_user=get_current_user_id();// to fetch the right data for the right user

  // ياخذ اليوم والشهر والسنه الي اختارها اليوزر
global $wpdb;
$d=date('j');//define variable to store the day
$m=date('m');//define variable to store the month
$y=date('Y');//define variable to store the year
$daily_amount= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT daily_amount FROM arduino_period_use where ID=$current_user and day=d and month=$m and year=$y ");
//print_r($daily_amount); 
        }

// ]]></script
```

Comment: i think you are so confused about php (server side script) and javascript (client side script) maybe research some php - js - Ajax

Comment: In your query, `day=d`, should be `day=$d`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you had some error checking, you'd get told about your SQL syntax errors:

```
$daily_amount= $wpdb->get_var("[..snip..] and day=d and month=$m and year=$y ");
                                                  ^---- missing $
```

You're unlikely to have a `d` field in your DB, so the query will failed with unknown field errors.

Comment: I Modified  $d and tried once again did not succeed code

Comment: then you need to explain **HOW** this code isn't working.

Comment: I choose the date but when i click the on the button does not show a result

Comment: use `var_dump($daily_amount)` instead. if get_var fails or doesn't find anything, it returns a null, which print_r will dump out as an empty string (invisible).

Comment: Do you call up the button true ?
I think the problem on the button

Comment: I want to ask Question        
When the user selects a date can store the day in $d , the month in $m and the year in $y

Answer (score 0):

The problem is PHP is a server side language and doesn't operate in quite the same way (at all) as javascript, it looks as though you have the two confused some what.

Look into ajax request using javascript to communicate with server side PHP code to access your database records

Comment: I want to ask Question

Comment: When the user selects a date can store the day in $d , the month in $m and the year in $y